# flic.kr/s/ short url for sets base58 issue

Tags: encoding, flickr, phpflickr

I am having trouble with flickr short urls, specifically those generated for sets.

#### Photos

I can see that for individual photos, if I select share and get the short url, they I would get `flic.kr/p/{base58_encode(photoid)}`. I can easily decode and encode the photoid and get the correct values.

#### Sets

I have tried the same for sets. If I select share on a set and get the short url, then I would get something like `flic.kr/s/{base58_encode(setid)}`. However, I am not sure that it is base58 encoded this time as decoding/encoding setid's with a base58 encoder/decoder does not return the correct values.

So, the question is, are the setid's encoded with a different encoder, or is there some sort of salt used with sets?

Many thanks in advance.